# Using PrimeNG growl module in angular 9

Tags: angular, primeng, angular9

I've just updated my project to Angular 9. Also I've updated PrimeNG to 9.1.2. Now my

```
import {GrowlModule} from 'primeng/primeng';
```

is not working, it says there is no `GrowlModule` in that directory. I know that in version 9 some imports has changed so I've also tried `primeng/api` but it's not there neither. Can someone tell me where to look for this module?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Growl is deprecated since [v6](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v6.1.7/#/growl), use Toast instead.

[image]